# How to get iPhone Device Activity

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-motion, uiaccelerometer

I want to get whether iPhone device is stationary, walking, In car etc.

Can I get it through Core Motion Framework?

CMAcceleration only gives x, y and z values.

How to use this value to calcluate iPhone Device Activity

Answer (score 1):

An accelerometer measures *acceleration* (change in velocity).

Those values are acceleration in the X, Y, and Z directions.  If the phone is stationary (or traveling at a constant velocity) then those values will be ~zero.

[How can I find the velocity using accelerometers only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085583/how-can-i-find-the-velocity-using-accelerometers-only)

Comment: Thanks for reply. But when I am walking or I am in the car still acceleration values not changing drastically. Even when my phone is on the table acceleration values are changing with same rate as when I am walking or in a car.

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre Exactly. Because when you are moving in a car, you are traveling at a relatively constant velocity. Change in velocity over time (`dv/dt`) is ~= 0. Just as if you were sitting still. It's an accelerometer, not a velocimeter.

Comment: What you can do, is assume an initial velocity of zero, and then perform a continuous integration of the acceleration over time, to keep an estimated velocity. Understand though, that the device has no way of actually knowing the velocity (aside from GPS, etc.)

Comment: It just dawned on me that a moving [RMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) of the acceleration may provide the kind of "activity" or general movement information you are looking for.  Basically this would pick up more back-and-forth type movement.

Comment: iOS 7 providing CMMotionActivity framework to get device state stationary, 
walking,                                                      running, 
automotive,                                                       unknown, property.                                               I want to achieve this for iOS 6. So I thought to do with CoreMotion.