# Questions about the Android Accelerometer Values

Tags: android, accelerometer

I have a couple of questions about the android accelerometer values.

Please take note that I am using a 2.2 version (very old phone I know), so the linear acceleration values couldn't be obtained.

I am using the accelerometer to measure some gait patterns for my project.

So my first question is, why does the accelerometer give high values when attached to the leg like +-10-40 m/s^2? Isn't it impossible for a human to attain that kind of acceleration considering that Usain Bolt only ran at about an acceleration of ~10m/s^2?

My second question is, how do I manually remove the gravity from the sensor values? Is that what is causing the high values? I saw this code from the Android documentation:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
     {
          // alpha is calculated as t / (t + dT)
          // with t, the low-pass filter's time-constant
          // and dT, the event delivery rate

          final float alpha = 0.8;

          gravity[0] = alpha * gravity[0] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[0];
          gravity[1] = alpha * gravity[1] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[1];
          gravity[2] = alpha * gravity[2] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[2];

          linear_acceleration[0] = event.values[0] - gravity[0];
          linear_acceleration[1] = event.values[1] - gravity[1];
          linear_acceleration[2] = event.values[2] - gravity[2];
     }
```

How do I obtain the initial value of gravity[0] etc? Because it looks like a circular reference (the formula used to obtain gravity[0] uses gravity[0] as well - which I don't have). Unless this formula means using another sensor to obtain the gravity?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't measure speed. It measures acceleration relative to the device's accelerometer.  You can get speed using the Maps API.

The gravity[] array is the accelerometer values. In this example they multiply by alpha to create a low pass filter because the sensor is very sensitive. To remove the gravity constant, subtract the force of gravity. You can get the force of gravity constant from SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, I am after the acceleration as well and not the speed (I realized I put speed, I edited it). It's just that I read this http://www.wired.com/wiredscience/2012/08/maximum-acceleration-in-the-100-m-dash/ and it's saying that the maximum is around 10, and that humans cannot tolerate more than that or something. So is it normal for the accelerometer to get high values like mine?

Comment: Also, isn't the event.values array the one that contains the accelerometer values? Thanks!

Comment: It measures gravity. There should be a constant net force of about 9.8m/s^2. Totally normal to get values like that. It's not speed speed would be measured in m/s, not m/s^2

Comment: Yes. They multiply the contents of values[] * (1-alpha), then load that less values into linear_accel. It's not easy to calculate speed with the accelerometer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085583/how-can-i-find-the-velocity-using-accelerometers-only

Comment: Alright, so if I understood correctly, the values of the gravity[] array are just constants of 9.8? Thanks for the links, I'll read up on those on when I need them, right now I just need to get acceleration values haha.

Comment: @LevLeetian  have u got values from accelerometer after using bypass or low pass filter what should be the value of gravity[0],gravity[1] ,gravity[2]

Answer (score 0):

For your second question, I was confused about it too, you just need to initialize gravity with event.values in the first loop.