# Getting speed from accelerometer

Tags: javascript, api, accelerometer

Hi guys I have a JavaScript function to get acceleration. I would like to get speed using the acceleration.

Could someone help me, please? There is no method to get *speed* in the API.

```
function getDataFromSensor() {
  //call js.call to get data FROM accelerometer  
  var rtrn = js.call('api.sensors.getAccelerometer()', {});
  // parse JSONObject
  var obj = JSON.parse(rtrn);
  //get value of axe x
  var x = obj.accelerometerX;
  //get value of axe y 
  var y = obj.accelerometerY;
  //get value of axe z
  var z = obj.accelerometerZ;
  // use gravity according to your place in this example I Choose 9 
  var result = (x * x + y * y + z * z) / (9 * 9);
  //If mobile move any direction then the following condition will become true 
  if (result > 2) {
    //Generate random number between 0 and 1 every time and display on text view

    js.setProperty('menu.Text_1', 'text', "err");
  } else {
    js.setProperty('menu.Text_1', 'text', "result:" + result);
  }

}
```

Comment: Aren't accelerometers device specific? Is there a particular device you are targeting?

Comment: i'm using a Huawei Ascend G730
the problem is that i can use only accelerometer api in the platform
and my purpose is to get the speed

Comment: This may be helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085583/how-can-i-find-the-velocity-using-accelerometers-only. It seems you need to do some calculating to reach a speed from accelerometer data.